# Do I have to use '/*' in order to show remark? Because it keeps getting errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently started learning Oracle SQL Developer.
I have some issues using `*/`

Here is my code:

```
SELECT * from emp;
SELECT ENAME,
    TRUNC((sysdate - hiredate)/7) AS "service days",
    TRUNC(sysdate - hiredate) AS "service weeks",
    MOD(trunc(sysdate - hiredate),7) AS "next week"
FROM emp
ORDER BY "service weeks" DESC;
```

I got the results I want. But some blogs say I should use '/*' in order to show multiple remarks.
So I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp;
SELECT ENAME,
    TRUNC((sysdate - hiredate)/7) AS "service days",
    TRUNC(sysdate - hiredate) AS "service weeks"/*,
    MOD(TRUNC(sysdate - hiredate),7) AS "next week"/*,
FROM emp
ORDER BY "service weeks" DESC;
```

I put two `/*` next to `service weeks`, and `next week`, and
it keeps throwing errors.
Can anyone tell me how to use `/*` clearly?

The error that I got is:

> "next week" columns is gone.

---

Here is the right result:

[image: right_example]

And here is the wrong one:

[image: wrong_example]

Comment: What error message did you get?  "ORA-01742: comment not terminated properly"?  If so, you need to complete the comment with a `*/`.

Comment: oh the error i got is simple. Just a result error,  "serice weeks" and "next week" columns are gone.

Comment: Generally if `/*` is used to *open* a multi-line comment, then the reverse, `*/` is the notation used to *close* the comment.  In that case, the second `/*` should be changed to `*/`. In other words, `/* .. */`  Otherwise, I may not be understanding your question :-)

Comment: Also, when reporting an error, make sure to type in the *exact*  error message.  Character by character, not your interpretation of its meaning.  Exact error messages are recognized by experienced users, can hold key information to the solution, and are also useful search terms.

Comment: Also, I do not think you want a `,` at the end of the line with `MOD`.

Comment: FYI, if you provide a minimal example table - just enough info that the query should work in theory, then we can test our code to confirm before proposing it to you, rather than shooting in the dark.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Best of look in finding your answers.

Comment: thank you! I will put error messages next time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: NP. It's a good practice to go ahead and edit this post to include the proper error message. It will be useful for future visitors, and is good follow through on all posts.  PS. was the error simply due to the  comma? Or was `/*` an issue as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
SELECT * from emp;
SELECT ENAME,
    TRUNC((sysdate - hiredate)/7) AS "service days",
    TRUNC(sysdate - hiredate) AS "service weeks"/*,
    MOD(trunc(sysdate - hiredate),7) as "next week"*/
FROM emp
ORDER BY "service weeks" DESC;
```

I think it was a misunderstanding on how to mark both ends of a comment.
Begin a comment with `/*`; end it with `*/`.
The `/` is to the outside of both `*`, like this:
`/* .. */`.

You can see that the code between those two markers is greyed out, and the code before and after the comment markers is not.
In contrast, all the code after the first `/*` in your code is greyed out.
All of this greyed out "code" is being treated as a comment (ignored), and the SQL statement is incomplete.  This is likely the cause of your error.

Comment: I am not sure there should be a comma at the end of the line with `MOD`.  Might want to comment out, or delete that comma. Please confirm, or deny.

Comment: ah yes you are right. There is no need to put comma at the end of     MOD

Comment: @JeeWoongLee Great, I'll fix my code then.  Was the source of your error too?  Did your `/*` work as it was, or did `*/` work better ?

Comment: I understand how to use '/* , */' . Thank you. I think that blog has some problem with its own answer. For me both are not working, when I use */* , */ ' part of my result is gone. But as you told me before, this is because '/*' is shows the start and '*/' shows the end, so I finally know the reason why 'next week' is gone. Because at the end of  line 4 ~ line 5 are defined as a remark. Ain't I right?

Comment: And also seriously, so much thanks for fast reply and many help. Now I can review and more careful when I post my question at Stackoverflow. Hope you have a good day sir.

Comment: Yes.  It's True that not all blogs are quality, or even accurate.

Comment: You're very welcome!  I enjoy mentoring, teaching, and helping others.  You're a quick study :-) and will be a valuable member to the community.  Welcome to SO.